# JavaScript Import and Export

Tags: javascript

I want to export App Object direct after importing, Can I merge these two lines?

```
import App from './app.js';
export default App;
```

Comment: No. There is no way other than skipping this altogether and using the original file itself. Imho If you explain why you want to do this may be there will be better answers.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) states:

> Exporting defaults: The following syntax does not export a default export from the imported module:
>
> ```
> export * from …;
> ```
>
> If you need to export the default, write the following instead:
>
> ```
> import mod from "mod";
> export default mod;
> ```